# passing data to modal(bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multiple markers on google map and when i click them i need to open a modal window. The problem is every marker has a specific id and i need that id in each modal.

The modal html is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="imageModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code calling this function is :

```
function createMarker(pos, t, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,  // google.maps.Map
        index: t
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      $('#imageModal').modal();
      //alert("I am marker " + marker.index);
    });
    return marker;
 }
```

So in imageModal i need to access the marker.index information which is dynamic. How can i do that? any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think `index` is a [MarkerOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MarkerOptions) in Google Maps v3.

How I got this is, I used the `title` option in MarkerOption and it set to a dynamic string and then accessed it in the `addListener` event.

Here's how you can do it:

```
function createMarker(pos, t, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,  // google.maps.Map
        title: t   //where t must be a string
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      $('#imageModal').modal();
      alert("I am marker " + this.getTitle() );  
    });
 }
```

Hope this helps you!!